# Trying to run a file using an executable in Java

Tags: java, cmd

Basically, I want this to function the same way as when you right click on a file and say "Open with". However I am having trouble figuring out the correct way to do this from java.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

That's all I got, but I can't figure out how to run it with the executable. Would I need to run the executable and put this in as a parameter? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it really depends on the executable that you are calling..
for example `notepad`, it is pretty straightforward..

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c notepad.exe " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

but for many others, you might need to see its manual about using "arguments"..
and some even don't support argument usage..